# Is there a nice way to represent $\prod_{m=1}^{2^{n-1}} \cos\left(2^{m-1} x\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, closed-form, products

Does
$$\prod_{m=1}^{2^{n-1}} \cos\left(2^{m-1} x\right) \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{\sin\left(2^nx\right)}{2^n\sin x}?$$ I want a more rigorous way to derive this than my approach:

Using that $\sin(2x)= 2\sin x\cos x$, we can easily show that
$$\sin\left(2^m x\right) = 2^m\sin x\cos x \cos(2x)\cdots \cos\left(2^{m-1}x\right)$$ and the initial equality follows. What about something like
$$\cos^4\left(2^n x\right)-\prod_{m=1}^{2^{n-1}} \cos\left(2^{m-1} x\right)?$$ is there a nice way to represent this? Thank you!

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that. The last expression is now edited. Thanks!

Comment: Your approach is fine apart from needing to specify that $sinx\ne0$. For these cases you can show the product is $\pm 1$, which is the limit of the RHS as $x\to k\pi$.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind with the last expression is to use $cos2x=2cos^2x-1$. You can use it to get something like $8cos^4x=cos4x+4cos2x+3$. I haven't checked this but it might lead somewhere.

Comment: I will look into it; seems like that is the way to go. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think the upper limit of the products should be $n$, not $2^{n-1}$.